# QML Tableview horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am using `TableView` QML component, where each column width is set to the table total width divided by number of columns. This introduces some fraction parts and in result, a horizontal scrollbar is almost always visible in the bottom.

But I don't want to disable scrollbar as I have ability of changing column width and because of that scrollbar may be needed. So my problem is about initial showing of this `TableView` component. I want to get rid of that scrollbar when component is shown first time, but don't disable it for future usage.

I am new to QML and don't know all aspects of it, but solution that came to me is to set width of each column as I do, then for the last one get sum of all previous columns and set it's width to parent.width - that sum. Can you please help me to understand how can I implement this using QML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[columnWidthProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#columnWidthProvider-prop) is calculated once at adding column. I cant reproduce your bug with this. `contentWidth` become same as `width`

```
    TableView {
        id: table
        anchors.fill: parent

        columnWidthProvider: function (column) {
            console.log(parent.width , columns, parent.width / columns)
            // wdth is 0 here
            return parent.width / columns
        }

        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
            policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded 
        }

//....
    }
```

But i had same issue in another view. Solution was:

```
Flickable {

    id:view

    ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar {
        policy: (view.width - view.contentWidth < -3) ? 
            ScrollBar.AlwaysOff : ScrollBar.AsNeeded}

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried to use what you said several ways, but my widget doesn't load when I add that part of code. I use TableViewStyle, maybe in that case I need to do it somehow else, I tried to add that part to the style, but again it doesn't load.

Comment: put your code in question. my snipets works - i checked

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was trying various things, at the end I finally found that it's just importing issue (Visual Studio didn't give me any error or warning about that), in the project I want to do this QtQuick.Controls 1.0 is used and ScrollBar isn't available with that, do you know any solution using QtQuick.Controls 1.0 features?

Comment: I managed to do that, but thank you for idea, helped a lot

Comment: I using controls2