# Connect custom Scrollbar and Flickable

Tags: qt, binding, qml, qt5

I have a virtual large table, and an area that is real drawn. Depending on the position of the content, a certain part of the virtual table is displayed.
And now I'm trying in different ways to synchronize the content and the scrollbar.
In this case, the scrollbar jumps with the content.

## AreaScrollBar.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ScrollBar {
    id: root
    /// Virtual content size
    /// 50000
    property real virtualContentSize: 0

    /// Real content size
    /// 2000
    property real contentSize: 0

    /// Visible content size
    /// 500
    property real visibleSize: orientation === Qt.Horizontal ? width : height

    /// Position offset step.
    /// 100
    property real stepAreaPosition: 1

    /// The position of the component area [0 .. virtualContentSize - contentSize]
    property real areaPosition: 0

    /// [0 .. contentSize - visibleSize]
    property real positionInArea: 0

    property QtObject priv: QtObject {
        /// В запасе после перестроения
        readonly property real buffer: 0.2 * contentSize - (0.2 * contentSize) % stepAreaPosition
    }

    size: (orientation === Qt.Horizontal ? width : height) / virtualContentSize
    policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
    onPositionChanged: {
        console.log('onPosChanged', position)
        let arP = -1
        let pia = -1
        if (position < 0) {
            position = 0
        } else if (position + size > 1) {
            position = 1 - size
        }

        if (position * virtualContentSize + visibleSize
                > areaPosition + 0.9 * contentSize) {
            pia = priv.buffer
        } else if (position * virtualContentSize - areaPosition < 0.1 * contentSize) {
            pia = contentSize - (priv.buffer + visibleSize)
        } else {
            positionInArea = position * virtualContentSize - areaPosition
            return
        }

        arP = position * virtualContentSize - pia
        let arp2 = 0
        if (arP < 0) {
            arp2 = 0
        } else if (arP > virtualContentSize - contentSize) {
            arp2 = virtualContentSize - contentSize
        } else {
            arp2 = arP - (arP % stepAreaPosition)
        }

        positionInArea = position * virtualContentSize - arp2
        areaPosition = arp2
    }
}
```

## main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Window {
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Column {
        focus: true
        Keys.onDownPressed:  vSb.position += 10 / vSb.virtualContentSize
        Keys.onUpPressed:    vSb.position -= 10 / vSb.virtualContentSize
        Keys.onLeftPressed:  hSb.position -= 10 / hSb.virtualContentSize
        Keys.onRightPressed: hSb.position += 10 / hSb.virtualContentSize
        Row {
            Column {
                Text { text: qsTr("vSb.position %1").arg(vSb.position) }
                Text { text: qsTr("vSb.areaPosition %1").arg(vSb.areaPosition) }
                Text { text: qsTr("vSb.positionInArea %1").arg(vSb.positionInArea) }
            }
            Item {
                width: 100
                height: 1
            }

            Column {
                Text { text: qsTr("hSb.position %1").arg(hSb.position) }
                Text { text: qsTr("hSb.areaPosition %1").arg(hSb.areaPosition) }
                Text { text: qsTr("hSb.positionInArea %1").arg(hSb.positionInArea) }
            }
        }


        Rectangle {
            id: mainArea
            width: 500
            height: 500
            clip: true
            color: "gray"
            border.color: "darkgray"
            border.width: 3
            property int _rows: 50
            property int _columns: 10
            property int _virtualRows: 500
            property int _virtualColumns: 50
            property int _rectWidth: 90
            property int _rectHeight: 90
            property int _spacing: 10
            property int _virtualContentWidth: _virtualColumns * (_rectWidth + _spacing)
            property int _virtualContentHeight: _virtualRows * (_rectHeight + _spacing)

            Flickable {
                id: _flick
                anchors.fill: parent
                contentWidth: mainArea._columns * (mainArea._rectWidth + mainArea._spacing)
                contentHeight: mainArea._rows * (mainArea._rectHeight + mainArea._spacing)
                Column {
                    spacing: mainArea._spacing
                    Repeater {
                        model: mainArea._rows
                        Row {
                            property int rowInd: index
                            spacing: mainArea._spacing
                            Repeater {
                                model: mainArea._columns
                                Rectangle {
                                    id: rect
                                    property int columnInd: index
                                    width: mainArea._rectWidth
                                    height: mainArea._rectHeight
                                    color: "#3c324a"
                                    Column {
                                        Repeater {
                                            model: rect.height / 10
                                            Rectangle {
                                                width: rect.width
                                                height: 10
                                                color: Qt.lighter(rect.color, 1 + index * 0.1)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    Text {
                                        anchors.fill: parent
                                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                                        text: '[%2, %3]'.arg(rowInd).arg(columnInd)
                                        font.pointSize: 7
                                    }
                                    Text {
                                        anchors.fill: parent
                                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                                        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                                        text: ('content\n[%1, %2]'
                                               .arg(vSb.areaPosition / vSb.stepAreaPosition + rowInd)
                                               .arg(hSb.areaPosition / hSb.stepAreaPosition + columnInd))
                                        font.pixelSize: 15
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                interactive: true

                Binding on contentX {
                    value: {
                        console.log('_flick.contentX', _flick.contentX, hSb.positionInArea)
                        return hSb.positionInArea
                    }
                }

                Binding on contentY {
                    value: {
                        console.log('_flick.contentY', _flick.contentY, vSb.positionInArea)
                        return vSb.positionInArea
                    }
                }
            }
            AreaScrollBar {
                id: vSb
                orientation: Qt.Vertical
                stepAreaPosition: mainArea._rectHeight + mainArea._spacing
                virtualContentSize: mainArea._virtualRows * stepAreaPosition
                contentSize: mainArea._rows * stepAreaPosition
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.right: parent.right
                anchors.bottom: hSb.top

                Binding on position {
                    value: {
                        console.log('vSb.position', _flick.contentY,
                                    vSb.areaPosition, vSb.virtualContentSize)
                        return (_flick.contentY + vSb.areaPosition) / vSb.virtualContentSize
                    }
                }
            }

            AreaScrollBar {
                id: hSb
                orientation: Qt.Horizontal
                stepAreaPosition: mainArea._rectWidth + mainArea._spacing
                virtualContentSize: mainArea._virtualColumns * stepAreaPosition
                visibleSize: mainArea.width
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: vSb.left
                Binding on position {
                    value: {
                        console.log('hSb.position', _flick.contentX,
                                    hSb.areaPosition, hSb.virtualContentSize)
                        return (_flick.contentX + hSb.areaPosition) / hSb.virtualContentSize
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: performance]

Error when I try to drag the canvas
[image: error]

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand, you want this code to work like this but in another way?

Comment: now scrollbar jumps

Comment: oh, yes. now I see it.

Answer (score -1):

This was always the problem when Qt project added QML. People try to skip learning C++ and do everything in JavaScript.

You need to read the [TableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) documentation. A TableView is already Flickable and provides a rectangle view into a TableModel. No need to try re-inventing the wheel.

Then [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446405/qml-tableview-horizontal-scrollbar) for adding scrollbars to TableView.

The correct solution is always **create all data in C++, use QML for display only**.

As soon as people start trying to implement logic in QML/JavaScript the wheels come off the cart.

Comment: this is just an example. I need to show a model for many millions of lines. QML cannot work correctly with such a large table. that's why I make a custom scrollbar. And repeaters are just an example

Comment: Again, you didn't read. DATA GOES IN C++ MODEL. TableView is a window over the model and the scrollbar will work fine. It was designed to "view" over SQL cursors with millions of rows and hundreds of columns.

Comment: in reality, I see that the delegates are beginning to shift by many millions of lines.
`ListView { model: 10000000; delegate: Text { text: index; } }` - go to the end of the table

Answer (score -1):

Please test this code, I use some parts of your code but I didn't complicate it with the position I just use Flickable and Scrollbar, and the Repeaters that you use for creating your matrix.
I test it and in this way, scrollbars didn't jump.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Window {
    id:mainArea
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Flickable and Scrollbar ")

    property int _rows: 50
    property int _columns: 10
    property int _virtualRows: 500
    property int _virtualColumns: 50
    property int _rectWidth: 90
    property int _rectHeight: 90
    property int _spacing: 10
    property int _virtualContentWidth: _virtualColumns * (_rectWidth + _spacing)
    property int _virtualContentHeight: _virtualRows * (_rectHeight + _spacing)


    Flickable{

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        contentHeight: mColumnId.implicitHeight
        contentWidth:  mColumnId.implicitWidth



        Column{
            id : mColumnId
            anchors.fill: parent

            spacing: mainArea._spacing
            Repeater {
                model: mainArea._rows
                Row {
                    property int rowInd: index
                    spacing: mainArea._spacing
                    Repeater {
                        model: mainArea._columns
                        Rectangle {
                            id: rect
                            property int columnInd: index
                            width: mainArea._rectWidth
                            height: mainArea._rectHeight
                            color: "#3c324a"
                            Column {
                                Repeater {
                                    model: rect.height / 10
                                    Rectangle {
                                        width: rect.width
                                        height: 10
                                        color: Qt.lighter(rect.color, 1 + index * 0.1)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            Text {
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                                text: '[%2, %3]'.arg(rowInd).arg(columnInd)
                                font.pointSize: 7
                            }
                            Text {
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                                text: "Parisa"
                                font.pixelSize: 15
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar{}
        ScrollBar.horizontal: ScrollBar{}
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to show a certain part of the content, depending on the position of the scrollbar. The scrollbar has a much larger distance for scrolling than the actual size of the content.